# Is there a way in Python to uniformly add an element to a list no matter if it already exists?

Tags: python, list, append

If I have, for example, a dictionary `d` and I want to add the value `v` - amongst possibly more of them in a list - to the key `k`, I usually do it this way:

```
if k in d:
    d [k].append (v)

else:
    d [k] = [v]
```

Is there a more elegant way, e.g. like

```
list_append (d [k],  v)
```

? The problem occurs for me mainly at dictionaries but a solution should not be restricted to them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault):

```
d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the question because it was not made clear that there could be more elements in the value list.

Comment: @StephanGeue Strange, try it again, it worked for me